# How to match the rest of the list, no matter the length

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I want to write a function which takes a `list` of `String`s with pattern matching. For example I check for a keyword `set` like this:

```hs
parseArgs :: [String] -> Either String Command
parseArgs ["set", k, v] = Right $ Command k v
parseArgs ["set", _] = Left "To few arguments for set"
parseArgs ["set", _, _, _] = Left "To much arguments for set"
```

As you can see I want to match `parseArgs ["set", "key", "value", ...]`. 
But the current approach only gives me a match on `["set", "key", "value", "something"]` not for more entries.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "*cons*" list construction:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Either String Command
parseArgs ["set", k, v] = Right $ Command k v
parseArgs ["set", _] = Left "To few arguments for set"
parseArgs ("set": _: _: _) = Left "To much arguments for set"
```

`("set": _: _: _)` is a compact form of `("set": (_: (_: _)))` so we here match with a list that is non-empty, and where the tail is non-empty, and where that tail is non-empty, so a list that contains at least three elements.

In fact `["set", _, _, _]` is just *syntactical sugar* for `("set": (_: (_: (_:[]))))`. So by using a wild card `_` instead of an empty list `[]` at the tail, we leave it open what follows next.

You forgot the case where one simply passed `["set"]`, we can also use the same technique for that:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Either String Command
parseArgs ["set", k, v] = Right $ Command k v
parseArgs ("set": _: _: _) = Left "To much arguments for set"
parseArgs ("set":_) = Left "To few arguments for set"
```

This will thus match a singleton list, and a list with two elements, where the first element is each time `"set"`.

We can decide to parameterize the length check, like:

```
checkLength :: Int -> [a] -> Either String b
checkLength n _ | n < 0 = Left "Too much arguments"
checkLength n [] = Left "Too few arguments"
checkLength n (_:xs) = checkLength (n-1) xs
```

or even simpler with `drop`:

```
checkLength :: Int -> [a] -> Either String b
checkLength n = Left . foldr (const . const "Too much") "Too few" . drop n
```

Then we can thus check this as:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Either String Command
parseArgs ["set", k, v] = Right $ Command k v
parseArgs ("set": xs) = checkLength 2 xs
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very nice again! Would you go another approach than pattern matching with this? The More cases I have the more lines I need to write... Is there a better way for this?

Comment: @Biskit1943: but here there are three possible outcomes, so it looks like the three clauses are justified here. You could abstract the length comparison away, so creating a function that determines the length of a list, and use a parameter to either return `"Too much"` or `"Too few"`.

Comment: Yeah, but I have more commands than just `set` lets say I have three more, would you still use this?

Comment: @Biskit1943: no, as said before, you can abstract that away in a separate function.